# Sending asynchronous print jobs from the cloud

Tags: python, web-applications, printing, cloud

We have our logistics software which is an in house webapp written in python. We're aiming to move this onto Amazon but there are some hurdles surrounding how we would then send our print jobs.

Currently each station in the warehouse has a PC and a printer with a statically assigned address, the printers are all setup as network printers and are not installed onto any PC. The way print jobs are sent to the correct printer is with relationship tables that link the PC and printer IP's.

The barcodes are printed off completely automatically as soon as an item is scanned and the stock is checked by the operator at the station the print job is sent, there is no manual input from the user whatsoever.

We're struggling to come up with ways on how to move this software onto Amazon whilst retaining the exact same setup and functionality of the stations and printers.

I've only been able to find two ways to get around this without the use of a VPN:

The first way is using Google Cloud Print however this would mean we would need to go through and have each printer actually installed to each stations PC as well as having to manage Google accounts and which printers are with what account this is not entirely out of the question but it is really not desirable.

Secondly I've been looking at printers that are now 'Cloud' ready for example Zebra has a range of printers that can use WebSockets, is there some way we can use this?

Any input or further suggestions other then the two ways I mentioned would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Amazon, I think Amazon VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) is the good fit.

How it works is that you can create public and private subnets depending on whether you need public access to your servers. The server instances you bring up in either of these subnets can communicate directly with the printers in your current network by bridging the networks together with a VPN connection.

http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/

> Additionally, you can create a Hardware Virtual Private Network (VPN) connection between your corporate datacenter and your VPC and leverage the AWS cloud as an extension of your corporate datacenter.

This would allow the server instances in AWS directly access your printers to send jobs.

Comment: Use of a VPN of any kind if completely out of the question.
We currently have VPN's in place to external companies who also use this software but VPN's can often be unreliable especially when you don't have control of both ends.
Sorry I should've made this clearer.